# Is it possible to make v-for variables dynamic in vue?

Tags: vue.js

```
  <div class="col-3" v-for="n in 5"  :key="n">
      <h3>Table {{n}}</h3>
      <draggable class="list-group" :list="`list${n}`" group="people" @change="log">
        <div
          class="list-group-item"
          v-for="`(element, index) in list${n}`"
          :key="element.name"
        >
          {{ element.name }} {{ index }}
        </div>
      </draggable>
  </div>
```

Why can't I set the `v-for` or `:list` as a concatenated string? Is there any way around this?

Full code:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <component
    v-for="(component, index) in components"
    :key="index"
    :is="component"
  />
    <div class="col-3" v-for="n in listNumber"  :key="n">
      <h3>Table {{n}}</h3>
      <draggable class="list-group" :list="list${n}" group="people" @change="log">
        <div
          class="list-group-item"
          v-for="(element, index) in list${n}"
          :key="element.name"
        >
          {{ element.name }} {{ index }}
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
let id = 1;
export default {
  name: "two-lists",
  display: "Two Lists",
  order: 1,
  components: {
    draggable,
    list:[],
  },
  data() {
    return {
      
      list1: [
        { name: "John", id: 1 },
        { name: "Joao", id: 2 },
        { name: "Jean", id: 3 },
        { name: "Gerard", id: 4 }
      ]
      },
      {
      list2: [
        { name: "Juan", id: 5 },
        { name: "Edgard", id: 6 },
        { name: "Johnson", id: 7 }
      ],
    
    listNumber: 3,
    }
  },
  created(){
      console.log(this.list);
    },
  methods: {
    
    add: function() {
      this.list.push({ name: "Juan" });
    },
    replace: function() {
      this.list = [{ name: "Edgard" }];
    },
    clone: function(el) {
      return {
        name: el.name + " cloned"
      };
    },

  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The idea I had about this was for this to iterate, and for each iteration, pull items from different arrays. Is there a better way to go about this. Sorry for the bad formatting, new around here.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here, and why are you trying to use a string inside of `v-for`?

Comment: @maxshuty The first v-for is to create each list, and inside each list has components which is the inner div. All the info is stored inside a nested array.

Comment: I want the list${n} to be like list1, list2, list3, the name of the lists in the array

Comment: Thanks! What is `list`? Can you show the code how that is created?

Comment: @maxshuty I posted my code as it is right now

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do but it *looks* like you're trying to get a specific list in the `v-for` loop.

One way to fix your issue would be to nest your lists inside of an `object` in your `data` like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      listNumber: 3,
      lists: {
        list1: [
          { name: "John", id: 1 },
          { name: "Joao", id: 2 },
          { name: "Jean", id: 3 },
          { name: "Gerard", id: 4 }
        ],
        list2: [
          { name: "Juan", id: 5 },
          { name: "Edgard", id: 6 },
          { name: "Johnson", id: 7 }
        ],
      },
    };
```

And then in your code you can just do `` lists[`list${n}`] `` like this:

```
<div class="col-3" v-for="n in listNumber"  :key="n">
  <h3>Table {{n}}</h3>
  <draggable class="list-group" :list="lists[`list${n}`]" group="people" @change="log">
    <div
      class="list-group-item"
      v-for="(element, index) in lists[`list${n}`]"
      :key="element.name"
    >
      {{ element.name }} {{ index }}
</div>
```

There is a lot more refactoring and other cleanup you could (and should) probably do but this should at least get you over this hurdle.